# Blender graph editor bezier

Tags: animation, graph-editor

I know how it works in Autodesk Maya but I prefer Blender more. The problem is that in Graph Editor animations curves are not Bezier curves and it's not handy to use for animation. This way I can't handle the animation curves completely as in Maya. Here is example. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RGuHdP_b3sk
Can you add Bezier curves in Graph Editor?

Comment: Check here https://www.blender.org/manual/animation/editors/graph.html

Comment: @saiman please do not add the "[curves](http://blender.stackexchange.com/tags/curves/info)" tag. Read the description it is not about animation "curves" but rather an object type in blender.

Comment: Actually the question of animation curves

Comment: https://www.blender.org/manual/animation/editors/graph/fcurves.html

Comment: it might be sane to add [tag:F-Curve] tag ?

Comment: Take a look at my answer here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/52468/1170 
They are actually Bezier curves, but there are constraints placed on them to make sure they don't loop back on themselves. Apparently, Maya and Blender handle these constraints differently.

Answer (score 4):

On top of other forms of interpolation, blender does use Bezier curves in the Graph Editor

[image]

The interpolation modes for segments of a curve can be determined by selecting a point in the graph an pressing the <kbd>T</kbd> key.

[image]

Or on the menu Key->Interpolation Mode:

[image]

Moreover the default interpolation mode can be determined in the preferences (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>)[image]

Some examples.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]